# Setting value of a column based on values of other columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Pandas dataframe:

[image]

This is some fictional data about games of cricket played between two countries. I want to set the value of column winner based on this simple logic:

```
if country_1_runs == country_2_runs:
    winner = 3
elif country_1_runs > country_2_runs:
    winner = 1
else:
    winner = 2
```

I know about map and apply methods in Pandas. But I'm not certain if they allow conditional expressions like the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df.country_1_runs == df.country_2_runs
m2 = df.country_1_runs > df.country_2_runs

df['winner'] = np.select([m1, m2], [3, 1], default=2)
```

Comment: This is a really elegant solution.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader - Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df['winner'] = np.where(df['country_1_runs'] == df['country_2_runs'], 3, 
    np.where(df['country_1_runs']> df['country_2_runs'], 1, 2))
```