# pandas: set value of column to true if the value = yes in any of a subgroup of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to set the value of a new column based on values in a group of 14 columns in my database of 200+ columns equals.

If all are null, set as 'Invalid',
If value = 'Yes' for any, set as 'True', else 'False'

Example below for a subset of 3 columns:

```
   A        B         C
1       
2           Yes       Yes
3  No       Yes       Yes
4  No       Yes       Yes
5  No       No        N/A
```

desired output:

```
   A        B         C     D
1                           Invalid 
2           Yes       Yes   True
3  No       Yes       Yes   True
4  Yes                      True
5  No       No        N/A   False
```

I adapted the following [Setting value of a column based on values of other columns in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243213/setting-value-of-a-column-based-on-values-of-other-columns-in-pandas-dataframe) to do this:

```
m1 = dfMSR['A'] == 'Yes'
m2 = dfMSR['B'] == 'Yes'
m3 = dfMSR['C'] == 'Yes'
dfMSR['D'] = np.select([m1 | m2 | m3], [True], default = False)
dfMSR['D'] = np.where(((dfMSR['A'].isnull()) &
                       (dfMSR['B'].isnull()) &
                       (dfMSR['C'].isnull())), 
                      'Invalid', dfMSR['D'])
```

This works but I don't fancy writing the code to expand to 14 columns. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with test at least one value `Yes` in [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and then test if all values are misisng by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
#columns for test, in real data 14 columns names
cols = ['A','B','C']
m1 = dfMSR[cols].eq('Yes').any(axis=1)
m2 = dfMSR[cols].isna().all(axis=1)

dfMSR['D'] = np.select([m1, m2], [True, 'Invalid'], default=False)
print (dfMSR)
     A    B    C        D
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  Invalid
2  Yes  Yes  NaN     True
3   No  Yes  Yes     True
4   No  Yes  Yes     True
5   No   No  NaN    False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try check for nan first, then check for `YES`. Then use `np.select`:

```
df['D'] = np.select((df.isna().all(1), df.eq('Yes').any(1)),
                    ('Invalid', True), False)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C        D
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  Invalid
2  NaN  Yes  Yes     True
3   No  Yes  Yes     True
4   No  Yes  Yes     True
5   No   No  NaN    False
```

Comment: Quang, in your code how are you limiting the check to columns A, B and C from the 200+ cols in the df?

Comment: oh, then you list the columns, similar to jezzrael's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ***apply()*** method could help you (even though there are more direct ones in this specific case, I think this general one could help.)

First, a little DataFrame as an example :

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame([[True, True, False], 
                       [True, True, True], 
                       [True, None, True]])
    df.columns= ['A', 'B', 'C']
    df
```

So you will have:

```
        A   B   C
    0   True    True    False
    1   True    True    True
    2   True    None    True
```

Then you can define a function to apply to the set of columns row-wise. The one I give as an example return *None* if there is one None in the list, or perform an *and*. You can adapt to your case easily

```
    def all_true(x):
        y = True
        for i in x:
            if(type(i) != bool):
                return None
            y &= i
        
        return y
```

So this will return False :

```
   all_true([False, True, False])
```

Now if you apply this function to *df*:

```
    df.apply(all_true, axis = 1)
```

you will have

```
    0    False
    1     True
    2     None
    dtype: object
```